# Making Ehcache persistent with Production ReDeployment Strategy

Tags: weblogic, ehcache

My application that uses persistent Ehcache gets deployed as an ear file on the weblogic server. The deployment stategy used is the Production redeployment Strategy

(Production redeployment strategy involves deploying a new version of an updated application alongside an older version of the same application. WebLogic Server automatically manages client connections so that only new client requests are directed to the new version. Clients already connected to the application during the redeployment continue to use the older version of the application until they complete their work, at which point WebLogic Server automatically retires the older application.)

Since the Ehcache of the new version application is configured before the ehcache of the older version is shutdown (since the application is still running), the index and data files are not even created and used.
Hence persistence doesn't work.

What could i do to make the cache persistent? I wanted that somehow ehcahche manager stops while deploying new version in weblogic.

Regards